# how to retrieve specific value from file using Python

Tags: file, text, python-3.6

i have a text file which contain several lines in the end of the file I have the following line: "Total: 235267878"
my question is: How do I retrieve the specific value (235267878) and set it to a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't specify how long your file can be, we can iterate through the file:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if 'Total:' in line:
            totalValue = line.split(':')[-1].strip()

print(totalValue)
```

In this solution I assume that the line we are looking for always has the form `Total: {number}`. We open the file in the **read only mode** and iterate through the lines (In my exmaple the file is called *test.txt*). After the line containing the total value is found, we split it and remove possible white spaces to get the number. The variable `totalValue` contains the number you are looking for.

Comment: what does it means [-1].strip() in this case?

Comment: @ErezN first we split the line with line.split(':'). It returns a list of the form ['Total', ' 235267878']. Note that there is no ':' symbol in the list since we specified it as a separator in the split method. With list[-1] we get the last element of the list which is ' 235267878'. Now we have the number as a string with leading whitespace which we have to remove. strip() does exactly this and cuts whitespaces left and right. In our case lstrip() would also be ok since we have the whitespace only left but to make the code more robust I prefered to use strip().

Comment: and if my file contains this in the last line of the file: 

total:78727  partial:51257673

and I still want to strip only the value of total what should I do?

Comment: @ErezN  if the last line contains multiple key-value pairs, the naive approach  is: 1) split the whole line on whitespaces 2) find pair you are interested in 3) split this pair on ':' 4) get the value

Comment: Can you provide code example in Python for this approach?